# Warum benutzt man hier die Konjunktiv II Gegenwart aus dem Präteritumstamm?

Tags: subjunctive

Ich lerne jetzt seit ein paar Jahren Deutsch, und habe gemerkt, dass man bei regelmäßigen Verben sehr selten die Konjunktiv II-Form aus dem Präteritum bildet, vielleicht so gut wie nie im gesprochenen, aber auch selten im geschriebenen (zumindest in Büchern usw., die ich gelesen habe). Aber ich bin heute Morgen diesem Abschnitt begegnet:

> Frank bemerkte, daß sie beim Trinken ihre Zunge in das Glas steckte.
> So etwas hatte er noch nie gesehen. Er hätte sie gerne gefragt, was
> das sollte, es kam ihm ziemlich albern vor, aber er wußte, dass es bei
> Martin Klapp nicht gut ankommen würde, wenn er jetzt mit ihr auch noch
> über solche Sachen **redete**.

Ich würde "reden würde" statt "redete" erwarten. Dieser Text ist aus Neuer Vahr Süd von Sven Regener, 2004 veröffentlicht, einem Buch, das in einem ziemlich lässigen und oft umgangssprachlichen Stil geschrieben ist, deswegen hat mich das "redete" umso mehr überrascht. Ich weiß natürlich, dass beide Formen eigentlich korrekt sind, aber ich habe die hier verwendete Form sehr selten gesehen, da frage ich mich, ob es einen Grund gibt, warum diese Form des Konjunktivs hier passt.

Der Klarheit halber füge ich hinzu, dass ich verstehe, dass es bei Modalverben und bestimmten unregelmäßigen Verben nicht so unerwartet ist, dass die Konjunktiv II-Form aus dem Präteritum gebildet wird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vermutlich stilistische Gründe: Voraus geht der Nebensatz "dass es nicht gut ankommen würde" - dann möchte man nicht den nächsten Teilsatz mit "...reden würde" genauso enden lassen. Vielleicht einfach, weil Variation schöner ist. Vielleicht auch, um die Verarbeitung zu erleichtern: Der Wechsel der Form hilft vielleicht zu signalisieren, dass die beiden Teilsätze nicht syntaktisch parallel sind (der Wenn-Satz ist "anders", da in den ersten eingebettet).

Answer (score 2):

Es liegt an der Konjunktion *wenn*. Diese schließt das Präteritum aus, denn dann würde man stattdessen *als* oder *falls* verwenden müssen.

Also muss *redete* als Konjunktiv II gedeutet werden. Die Umschreibung mit *reden würde* ist zwar möglich, aber auch nicht eindeutiger.

Comment: Das stimmt sicherlich im Ergebnis, aber die Beobachtung des Fragestellers, dass statt des Konjunktivs Präteritum sehr oft auf die *würde*-Konstruktion ausgewichen wird, gilt ja nicht nur im Fall von Modusambivalenz. Insofern ist die Einsicht, dass *redete* hier eindeutig eine Konjunktiv-Präteritum-Form ist, zwar nicht falsch; sie dürfte aber für sich genommen noch nicht die Frage beantworten, warum der Konjunktiv Präteritum überhaupt verwendet wird.

Comment: Um sich wichtig zu machen.

Comment: In meiner Schulzeit wurde mir noch eingetrichtert: "Wenn-Sätze sind würdelos", die Umschreibung ist also nicht möglich. Generell wird der Konjunktiv Präteritum verwendet, um Zweifel am Mitgeteilten zu implizieren bzw. das Gesagte der Sphäre der Realität zu entfernen. Berühmtes Beispiel aus "Wallenstein": "Mir meldet er aus Linz er **läge** krank". Hätte Wallenstein kommentiert, er meldete, daß er "liege", so hätte er wohl kaum nachgefaßt, er habe "sich're Nachricht, daß er sich [...] versteckt beim Grafen Gallas", oder? Dann hätte er die Lüge nämlich nicht durchschaut.

Comment: Interessant. Also war das tatsächlich mal eine Regel.